# Have Pycco recognize doctests as code?

Tags: python, docco

Is there any way to have Pycco recognize doctests as code and render them appropriately?

E.g. the docstring of the following function

```
def fib(i):
    """ Fibonacci number

    >>> fib(10)
    55
    """
    if i < 2:
        return i
    else:
        return fib(i-1) + fib(i-2)
```

Renders In Pycco like the following

```
Fibonacci number

           fib(10) 5
```

Clearly the `>>>` was interpretted as indentation and code highlighting did not take effect.  This seems like a common use case.  is there a plugin somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: Looking at the code, comments are processed by markdown, so the `>>>` prompt is interpreted as the start of a quote section. If you want more formatting options, you might have to look elsewhere; `sphinx` is the canonical choice, and does support doctests (see e.g. http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/doctest.html).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware.  I was hoping that this might be special cased in some plugin somewhere due to it's prevalence.

Comment: FWIW, doctests are convenient when you're using CPython exclusively, but if you introduce Pypy, Jython or IronPython (or a different version of CPython...), doctests can be a hindrance.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't mind if the `doctest` suite is indented an additional four characters compared to the rest of the docstring, as long as it's internally consistent, so the following will pass the tests just fine (tested in 2.7.9 and 3.4.2):

```
def test():
    """Doctest test

    The following are doctests:

        >>> test()
        'foo'

    That went well.

    """
    return 'foo'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

This additional indentation will be interpreted as a code block by `pycco`, just as it is in the Markdown here on SO. The above test renders in HTML as follows:

[image: Screen grab of rendered pycco HTML]